# Eclipse not opening jvm out of date mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm

I am on a mac and try to program java with newer versions of eclipse, but they are not working. Old versions of eclipse are working, but I recently installed Eclipse Luna and when I open it, it says: "Version 1.6.0_31 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.7 or greater is required." But I have the newest version of java installed. I installed the newest version of the JDK, and if I'm not mistaken, JVM is Java virtual machine but I don't know how to update that. I am expirienced with java, however I am beginner to how stuff like the JVM works, so please try to be as specific as possible when explaining the answer. Also explain why it works and why it wasn't working before. I searched on this site before posting and one answer to a similar problem was to type

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
```

into terminal, but terminal gave me the error:

```
 -bash: export: `/usr/libexec/java_home': not a valid identifier
 -bash: export: `-v': not a valid identifier
 -bash: export: `1.7': not a valid identifier
```

So please help, I don't know what to do.

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)` is what you may have needed to type, but you need to have the 1.7 JDK installed, which is available for download from java.com.

Comment: @Petesh write an answer about it?

Comment: What does "java -v" give you on your terminal right now?

Comment: @Petesh It said that there is no such file or directory, but I did install the JDK 7. The installer said installation successful, but maybe it didn't work, but I wouldn't know why.

Comment: @Swapnil java -v says: 


    "Unrecognized option: -v"
    "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine."
    "Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to verify that you've installed the 1.7 or newer JVM. To do this you do:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home --verbose
```

This command is built-in to mac OS X, and will list all the known java environments available. If you don't see a 1.7 VM in the list then it's not been installed correctly.

Secondly, you need to ensure that the version of Eclipse you downloaded is compatible with the JVM. For example, I have the following JDKs installed:

```
1.8.0_05, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
1.7.0_55, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home
```

This means that I can use a 64bit (`x86_64`) version of eclipse with a 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 VM.

This means that I can use a 32bit (`i386`) version of eclipse with the 1.6 VM only because that is the only version that has a 32bit JDK.

The [Eclipsepedia installation page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.4_.28Luna.29) indicates that a 1.7 JDK/JRE is **required for most of the Luna package downloads based on Eclipse 4.4** (extracted from page).

So, make sure that you're using the 64bit downloads.

To determine the 32/64bit version of the eclipse instance that you downloaded, at a terminal go to the directory of the eclipse installation. In the same directory that has directories called: `Eclipse.app`, `configuration`, `plugins` there is a symlink to the `eclipse` binary. Run `file eclipse` and it will tell you the mode that it runs in; and if you get `x86_64` then it's a 64bit version, if you get `i386` then it's a 32bit version.

64bit:

```
$ file eclipse
eclipse: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

32bit:

```
$ file eclipse
eclipse: Mach-O 32-bit executable i386
```

Comment: These are all the JDKs I have installed:

1.7.0_55, x86_64: "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_31-b04-415, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_31-b04-415, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_65, x86_64: "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home

ItseemsIhave JDK 1.7 installed. I seem to have multiple versions of Java 7 that are both 64 bit. I don't see how that could be a problem but maybe it is.

Comment: Ok, this says you have a 1.7 VM installed, now you need to verify that you have a 64bit version of eclipse downloaded; because that's the only version that will work with those particular JDKs. From a terminal window run `file eclipse` on the file at the top-level of the extracted eclipse installation .tar.gz. If it doesn't return `x86_64` then go back to the eclipse site and download the 64bit version.

Comment: Yay! That fixed it. Thank you! I guess I just had the 32-bit version of eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue for quite a while. This helped in my case.
Run the following in your terminal..

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"
```

verify the change with `java -version` command..

Answer (score 1):

After installing the latest java SE run

export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"

it Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think the Java 1.6 version that you've on your system could be Apple's Java runtime. Starting Java 7, Apple has decided not to make their own port, you need to get it from Oracle.

It seems that there could be something wrong with your installation of Java. You can try removing existing Java installation(s) and you can install fresh copy of Java 7 from Oracle and then try running `java -v` first. If that works well, then you can set `JAVA_HOME` and go further.